# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'count' while using itertuples() method with dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, count, iteration

I am trying to iterate over rows in a Pandas Dataframe using the itertuples()-method, which works quite fine for my case. Now i want to check if a specific value ('x') is in a specific tuple. I used the count() method for that, as i need to use the number of occurences of x later.

The weird part is, for some Tuples that works just fine (i.e. in my case (namedtuple[7].count('x')) + (namedtuple[8].count('x')) ), but for some (i.e. namedtuple[9].count('x')) i get an AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'count'

Would appreciate your help very much!

Comment: Hi, please post your sample data, and you code that cause the error, and the error, with some format with code block. That would help you get the answer faster and more accurate, also help others in understanding your problems. Following link is general guideline: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, some columns of your DataFrame are of *object* type (actually a *string*)
and some of them are of *int* type (more generally - numbers).

To count occurrences of *x* in each row, you should:

1. Apply a function to each row which:

   - checks whether the type of the current element is *str*,
   - if it is, return *count('x')*,
   - if not, return *0* (don't attempt to look for *x* in a number).
2. So far this function returns a *Series*, with a number of *x* in each column
   (separately), so to compute the total for the whole row, this *Series* should
   be summed.

Example of working code:

Test DataFrame:

```
     C1   C2  C3
0  axxv  bxy  10
1    vx   cy  20
2    vv   vx  30
```

Code:

```
for ind, row in df.iterrows():
    print(ind, row.apply(lambda it:
        it.count('x') if type(it).__name__ == 'str' else 0).sum())
```

(in my opinion, *iterrows* is more convenient here).

The result is:

```
0 3
1 1
2 1
```

So as you can see, it is possible to count occurrences of *x*,
even when some columns are **not** strings.